# How to call sub folder controller with routing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am using CodeIgniter framework. I have files in my controllers folder like this:

```
 - Controllers
 --- admin.php - Admin Controller
 --- /Admin - Admin Folder
 ----- category.php - Category Controller in Admin folder.
```

The Url: `mysite.com/index.php/admin/category` says that page not found because it is trying to call the `category` function of `admin` controller but I want it to call the `index` function of `category` controller in `Admin` folder.

Also I am using the `admin` controller for create, edit etc. functions of `admin` controller like `mysite.com/index.php/admin/create`.

I think, I should use the `$route` array in config file. What routing should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the CI core. See `function _validate_request($segments)` in `system/core/Router.php`. This function attempts to determine the path to the controller. It goes through different conditions one by one and returns the result once a given condition is met. Besides the other, there are two conditions involved:

1. Is it a file? (`system/core/Router.php` line 271, CI 2.1.2)

   ```
   // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
   if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].'.php'))
   {
       return $segments;
   }
   ```
2. Is it a folder? (`system/core/Router.php` line 277, CI 2.1.2)

   ```
   // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
   if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0]))
   {
       // ...
   ```

In your case the function will return once the first of the two conditions is met, i.e. when `admin.php` file is found.

There are two solutions:

1. Rename the file or the folder and refactor the application respectively.
2. Change the default behavior by [extending the core](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html). Basically that would conclude in changing the sequence of conditions checking. This can be accomplished by creating `MY_Router` class:

   ```
   class MY_Router extends CI_Router
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   and rewriting the original `_validate_request()` function with changed sequence of conditions. So first checking for directory and then for function.

I would suggest the first solution, if it does not require too much refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your application/config/routes.php file, add something like this:

```
$route['admin/create'] = 'admin/category';
```

Comment: I want admin/category to be called from category controller's (which is in admin folder) index function.